# Unable to find signing report in the new android studio update

Tags: firebase, android-studio, sha1, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I updated my android studio to the latest version day before yesterday and now I can't find the signing report which used to be under Tasks in the Gradle section on the right hand side.

Comment: Could you please add the explicit version to which you updated Android Studio so people can better help you?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same "issue" (maybe it's a new feature, idk). But as a workaround, you can also use the command `./gradlew signingReport` in the terminal.

Comment: `./gradlew signingReport` doesn't work but `gradlew signingReport` works fine. thanks.

Comment: @TeachMeJava finally after a whole day, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Just Go In Settings

```
Ctrl + Alt + S or File --> Settings
```

Then Go To Experimental and uncheck Do not Build Gradle Task list during Gradle sync.

[First Set Of Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCkdn.png)

Then Click Apply Then Close The window and press Sync Project With Gradle Files .

[Second Set Of Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPmBq.png)

Walla!! Here You GO!!
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDvIn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to android view on android studio, and type

```
gradlew signingReport
```